# Make file header file dependency

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to add header file dependency in make file

I written rule

```
 ${OBJECTDIR}/%.o: %.cc %.h
 gcc  $(WarningLevel)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES)  -c  -o $@  $^
```

but there are two error

One for .cc file which don't have any .h files . It will give no rule to make. 
Second one is the object file build by rule give error at linking

> ```
> file format not recognized; treating as linker script
> ```

how can I achieve that ? (source file should be compile if header file is got modified )

Comment: Generally, you turn translational units into object files, and since header files and not standalone translational units, it seems odd that you list %.h as a dependency to begin with.

Comment: I think there is no simple solution here. Even `$(wildcard %.h)` will not work since functions are expanded **before** matching (I got bitten by this several times). You could 1) use something based on `$(shell find ...)`, `define`, `$(foreach)` and `$(eval)` but this is tricky, 2) use gcc's `-M` option family to generate dependencies for you. I usually go for the second one but I'm at work and I don't have an example right now for you.

Comment: The make file is tab sensitive. The gcc line should be `\tgcc <STUFF>` ie a tab character in-front of gcc.

Comment: For your information,
the way to generate dependency automatically is shown here
[Automatic Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites).
This might be helpful for you.

Comment: @Ise Wisteria thanks for link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you haven't shown us your link command. Secondly, you shouldn't be using `$^` here. `$^` expands to a list of all dependencies (here, the `.c` and the `.h`), but we only want to compile the `.c` file. Use `$<`, which expands only to the name of the first dependency:

```
${OBJECTDIR}/%.o: %.c %.h
        gcc $(WarningLevel) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a rule for the header file dependency you listed:

```
%.h:
    echo This is my build target for header files.
```

Make won't actually do anything with the %.h files, but atleast you're telling it to watch for file changes (which then cause the .o files to need recompilation).

Comment: If no file is produced, this will not work. Either add `touch $^` as a recipe (which will create an empty file), or try to use `.PHONY:%.h` which shouldn't be good either.

Comment: This is right answer for the .cc file without a .h file (though it is a bit of a hack).  The linking error is coming from the link command, which the OP doesn't show, so there's no way we can say what is wrong with that.

Comment: @chris linking error is for each .o file which is build using rule 
${OBJECTDIR}/%.o: %.cc %.h
 gcc  $(WarningLevel)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES)  -c  -o $@  $